# Do my URIs have to be so long and explicit?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, unity-container

I'm writing a **modular application** using Microsoft Prism and Unity. My application's Shell project loads various DLLs which all include their own /resources or /images folder and user interface views. Each module, therefore, is a DLL.

When I'm trying to use a resource in my application, it seems I have to be very explicit about its location to make it work. For example, to locate an image in the same module/dll:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/MyCompany.MyProduct.MyModule;Component/Images/ZoomIn.gif" />
```

Do I really have to use the long form version of the URI everytime? I've tried shorter versions such as:

```
pack://application:,,,/Images/ZoomIn.gif

Images/ZoomIn.gif

ZoomIn.gif
```

etc.

I thought perhaps the 2nd version there should work. When I see Uri examples they often say "relative to the current assembly". Is this the assembly that is the executable that is running? Or is this the assembly that the code belongs to (my library/module)?

**Update:**

With Peter Hansen's help, I was able to shorten it to:

```
<Image Source="../Images/ZoomOut.png" />
```

Apparently I had to use the ../ because my view was in a subfolder. I also could leave off the pack:// syntax since the type converter does this for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few different options when it comes to retrieving binary resources in WPF, and they all depend on which kind of behavior you want.

1. If your resources should be embedded inside an assembly, add them to the project in Visual Studio, and set the *Build Action* to *Resource*. This way they will be baked into the assembly, and therefore can't be changed easily.
2. If they should be left as loose files, add them to the project, and set the *Build Action* to *Content*. Also make sure they are being copied to the output directory. This is a good idea, if you need to replace them frequently, and don't feel like recompiling the assembly every time.
3. If you want them as loose files, but don't want to include them in your Visual Studio solution for some reason (maybe they are not known at compiletime), you can access them using the full path or with something called SiteOfOrigin notation. I won't go into this as that is not relevant in your case.

To access the resources from your code you use a Pack URI, which can have different forms:

- `pack://application:,,,/img.jpg`
  References image in the root of the project.
- `pack://application:,,,/Folder1/Folder2/img.jpg`
  References image in a subfolder of the project.
- `pack://application:,,,/NameOfDll;Component/img.jpg`
  References image in a different assembly to which there is a reference in Visual Studio.

Luckily there is no need to write the full URI when a resource is referenced from XAML.
Basically the `pack://application:,,,` part can be avoided, because a TypeConverter exists that can translate part of the location to the full URI for you.

For points 1 and 2 above, the same XAML is used to reference the resources, regardless of whether they exist as loose files alongside the assembly at execution time or are embedded inside of it.

The fully defined explicit URI has to be used when referencing the resources from procedural code, though.

I have written some code and included some images, to show how this works.

[image: Image showing running program] 
[image: Image of solution explorer view]

Relevant XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Embedded in same assembly" />
    <Image Source="gift.png" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Embedded in same assembly in a subfolder" />
    <Image Source="Content/Images/gift.png" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Embedded in same assembly in a subfolder using full pack URI format" />
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Content/Images/gift.png" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Embedded in different assembly" />
    <Image Source="/Module1;Component/gift.png" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Embedded in different assembly in a subfolder" />
    <Image Source="/Module1;Component/Images/gift.png" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Embedded in different assembly in a subfolder using full Pack URI format" />
    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Module1;Component/Images/gift.png" />
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Setting imagesource from code-behind" />
    <Image x:Name="image1" />
</StackPanel>
```

Relevant code-behind:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Here we have to use the full Pack URI
    //image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Module1;Component/Images/gift.png")); //Throws exception..
    image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Module1;Component/Images/gift.png"));
}
```

**Update**
When the resource is in the same assembly that is using it, there should be no reason to include the `/NameOfDll;Component/` part of the URI. I'm not sure why it's not working in your case.

I have added a Window to Module1, that just references a single image in its own assembly, and that seems to work fine. The Window is shown when a button is clicked in the WPF application.

```
<Window x:Class="Module1.WindowTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Title="Window from Module1">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Images/gift.png" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Showing different window with resource shown]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But, in this example What if Module1 has Window2 and Window2 wants to show Module1/images/gift.png? This is the case that I have, I would think that Module1 could simple use "Images/gift.png" but, I'm having to type "/Module1;Component/Images/gift.png" for example.

Comment: Leaving off pack://application:,,, did save me a lot of room, thanks for that tip. I tried this before, but I did not realize I had to lead with /Module (instead of Module) and that is why it wasn't working

Comment: Oops just to note, I've tried "/Images/gift.png" as well (with preceding slash). If this is fact of life, then I'm willing to accept it, but I guess I was curious what was "in the same assembly" or not considering it seems to be in the same assembly, but not work

Comment: I would think it should work without having to write /Module1;Component/ - see my updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try to put together a sample application of my own that is a simple test.

Comment: Alright, found my last problem, I had my Module's Window in a /Views folder, so I had to do <Image Source="../Images/folderopen.ico"